# Hide value in app.config

Tags: visual-studio, c#-4.0, encryption, app-config

I have app.config file with keys and values:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Username" value="Admin" />
    <add key="Password" value="123456" />
    <add key="Port" value="22" />
  </appSettings>
```

I know that best way to secure data in config file is encrypt/decrypt with RSAprovider as web.config then export key and import on another user's machine (I have done this before), but I do not need such "safe" solution. 
I just want to hide password value to look like:

```
 <appSettings>
        <add key="Username" value="Admin" />
        <add key="Password" value="******" />
        <add key="Port" value="22" />
  </appSettings>
```

or just like empty string.
I have googled a lot and I could not find anything to hide, but plenty stuff about encryption.

Is this possible to achieve this somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, app configs are plain text.  If you had asterisks instead of the password, they would be interpreted as asterisks.

Comment: thnx, I know it will read like this unless there is "special key value" or settings but looks like nothing like this exist...

Comment: If nobody give solution nor I will find it out I will accept your answer, but it will take a few days.